# Calculate total for selected items in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a 3 tables each with multiple rows. I need to find a way to calculate the total of certain columns. Each row has a checkbox, so basically when this is checked, I need to be able to add that rows values to the total.

I currently have this, which is adding up the totals for each column, I just can not work out how to only do it when the checkbox is selected the total is then updated, and if deselected removed from the total.

Table Example...

```
<table class="transfer-group-table table table-hover tablesorter">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Invoice #</th>
        <th>Invoice Amount</th>
        <th>Order Status</th>
        <th>Payment Menthod</th>
        <th>Service Fee</th>
        <th>Funding Fee</th>
        <th>Delivery Date</th>
        <th>Transfer Amount</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="2942">

        <td>
            <p>A Company Ltd</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>18602</p>
        </td>
        <td class="AmountLoaned">
            <p>324.00</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>Completed </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>BACS</p>
        </td>
        <td class="ServiceCharge">
            <p>0.04</p>
        </td>
        <td class="FeeAmount">
            <p>4.54</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>May 29, 2015</p>
        </td>
        <td class="TransferAmount">
            <p>2.50</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="totalamountcb">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JavaScript...

```
// Calculate the total invoice amount from selected items only
function calculateInvoiceTotals() {
var Sum = 0;
// iterate through each td based on class and add the values
$(".AmountLoaned").each(function () {

    var value = $(this).text();
    // add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
        Sum += parseFloat(value);
    }
});
$('#TotalInvoiceAmt').text(Sum.toFixed(2));
};
// Calculate the total transfer amount from selected items only
function calculateTransferTotals() {
var Sum = 0;
$(".TransferAmount").each(function () {

    var value = $(this).text();
    // add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
        Sum += parseFloat(value);
    }
});
$('#TotalTransferAmt').text(Sum.toFixed(2));
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse using [`$.fn.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to `tr` then [`$.fn.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the `checkbox` using [`$.fn.is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) you can check whether checkbox is checked or not.

```
if($(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').is(':checked')){
    //Perform addition 
}
```

Complete Code

```
// Calculate the total invoice amount from selected items only
function calculateInvoiceTotals() {
    var Sum = 0;
    // iterate through each td based on class and add the values
    $(".AmountLoaned").each(function() {
        //Check if the checkbox is checked
        if ($(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
            var value = $(this).text();
            // add only if the value is number
            if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
                Sum += parseFloat(value);
            }
        }
    });
    $('#TotalInvoiceAmt').text(Sum.toFixed(2));
};
// Calculate the total transfer amount from selected items only
function calculateTransferTotals() {
    var Sum = 0;
    $(".TransferAmount").each(function() {
        //Check if the checkbox is checked
        if ($(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
            var value = $(this).text();
            // add only if the value is number
            if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
                Sum += parseFloat(value);
            }
        }
    });
    $('#TotalTransferAmt').text(Sum.toFixed(2));
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shbj8egm/)

Comment: looks good, but doesn't seem to want to work. Its not adding the 2 totals

Comment: @thatuxguy, I have only added `$(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').is('checked')` condition rest is your code

Comment: strange, it tally's up the totals without that.

Comment: @thatuxguy, My bad missed `:` in `is(':checked')` See http://jsfiddle.net/shbj8egm/